# Playing youtube videos with progressive downloading

Tags: ios, youtube-api, video-streaming

My application has a custom video player which should be played with youtube links (just to save me the hassle and money from making my own server side and stream videos from there).

***Here are some facts that I believe are true:***

- *Youtube prohibits any use of custom players except UIWebView and MPMoviePlayerController.*
- *Youtube doesn't share rtsp links for iOS devices, so I'm left with progressive downloading.*
- *Apple clearly states in the documentation that progressive downloading is possible only for small clips (under 10 minutes or 5MB/5min ratio).*

I've downloaded the application 'iTube' which allows you to watch youtube links with playlist control in the device. I was wondering how did they make it work for them. The app obviously uses progressive download as it downloaded 30MB after I've watched ~1 minute of the video (over 3G).

**Question**: Does Apple allow applications to break the policy of progressive download when youtube links are involved (because youtube doesn't offer any alternative)? or is this application just went under Apple's radar?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK as it turns out, this application just slipped under Apple's radar.

I've asked this question in the developer's forum and got the answer from one of Apple's employees:

> You would have to disable downloading over cellular if the clip is over 10 minutes.
>
> I'll forward this to the app review people.

The question I've asked is here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/966814#966814
(You need developer account to get in there)

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

If your video longer than 10 minutes, you need to use HLS streaming for your apps. For example  you can upload your videos to http://int10h.com get HLS link and stream. Good luck